# How to prevent "ATOMIC_ERROR" with CloudKit?

Tags: atomic, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

The last few days I see that some users are generating a lot of errors that are labeled as "ATOMIC_ERROR" in the CloudKit dashboard Telemetry view. I have search a bit on this, but I see only some documentation related to CloudKit JS. I don't use that, I just use the standard CloudKit library within a multiplatform macOS/iOS/tvOS app.

- To which CKError does ATOMIC_ERROR map? CKErrorPartialFailure
  perhaps?
- What's the universal way to replicate this error?
- How to prevent this error?

**BTW**:
I'm aware of property `isAtomic`. I always set property `isAtomic` in batch updates to false, because I don't need data integrity between multiple records in one zone. Therefore I don't expect 'atomic' related errors.

Comment: There have a property `isAtomic` in `CKModifyRecordsOperation`, maybe you can start your investigation from that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifyrecordsoperation/1447484-isatomic

Comment: I'm aware of property `isAtomic`. I always set property `isAtomic` to false, because I don't need data integrity between multiple records in one zone. Therefore I don't expect 'atomic' related errors.

Comment: Are you trying to upload ckrecord with a recordName that is already existed on iCloud server?

Comment: @wael I use `CKModifyRecordsOperation`. So when the recordName is unknown in iCloud, it will be added, otherwise the existing record will be updated.